# C'est quoi la différence entre Maîtrise d'oeuvre et Maîtrise d'ouvrage ?

Tags: sens, travail

Dans un contexte administratif, je suis toujours confronté à la situation de *Maîtrise d'oeuvre* et *Maîtrise d'ouvrage* ?

et qu'elle est la signification de chacun s'il vous plait ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La maîtrise d'œuvre va être la **conception du projet**, et de son organisation.

La maîtrise d'ouvrage a la *volonté* du projet et va s'assurer que celui-ci soit mené à bien en **respectant un cadre fixé par le client**. Elle peut être fait par le client ou par l'entreprise qui réalise le projet.

---

D'après le Wikitionaire :

> **[maîtrise d’œuvre](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ma%C3%AEtrise_d%E2%80%99%C5%93uvre)** *féminin*  `\met.ʁiz dœvʁ\`
>
> - (*Bâtiment et travaux publics*) Conception d'un bâtiment et direction des travaux. Mission du maître d’œuvre.
> - (*Par extension*) **Conception et réalisation d'un ouvrage** ou d'une partie d'un ouvrage.
>
> **[maîtrise d’ouvrage](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ma%C3%AEtrise_d%E2%80%99ouvrage)** *féminin* `\met.ʁiz du.vʁaʒ\`
>
> - (*Bâtiment et travaux publics*) Rôle de l’ordonnateur de travaux, du futur propriétaire de l’ouvrage terminé. rôle du maître d’ouvrage.
> - **Donneur d’ordre au profit de qui l’ouvrage est réalisé.**

Comment: Puis-je avoir un commentaire allant avec le downvote? Je pourrais peut être améliorer ma réponse?

Comment: Oui, pardon, c'est moi qui a désapprouvé, après quoi j'ai ajouté une réponse de mon propre cru. J'ai du relire ta réponse trois fois et je ne comprenais toujours pas. Alors que je sais ce que veulent dire MOA et MOE... j'apprécie beaucoup tes contributions, pas de mauvais sentiments, hein ;-) c'est juste cette réponse que j'ai trouvée confuse.

Comment: @RomainVALERI Est-ce mieux?

Comment: Vous pourriez même mentionner l'assistant à la maîtrise d'ouvrage qui peut être une entreprise complètement indépendante du reste.

Comment: @anderstood Cette tierce entreprise, peut importe quelle autre entreprise sous-traite, devra aider le maître d'ouvrage. Je préfère garder ma réponse aussi simple que possible.

Comment: C'est juste que la partie sur la maîtrise d'ouvrage est incomplète puisque parfois ce n'est pas elle qui s'assure que le projet est mené à bien. Dans ce cas il me semble plus simple de dire 'la maîtrise d'ouvrage a la volonté du projet et le fait réaliser par le maître d'oeuvre'.

Comment: @anderstood J'aime bien ta formulation, j'ai donc édité ma réponse

Answer (score 4):

Voici un mnémonique :

> À la fin de l'œuvre, il reste l'ouvrage.

- Celui qui paye récupère l'ouvrage, c'est le maître d'ouvrage.
- Celui qui est payé a œuvré, c'est le maître d'œuvre.

Answer (score 2):

Réponse courte :

Quand **une entreprise A (prestataire)** réalise un projet (par exemple, réaliser un site Internet) pour **l'entreprise B (client)** :

> **MOE** (maîtrise d'oeuvre) : les personnes de l'entreprise **A** chargées du projet
>   **MOA** (maîtrise d'ouvrage) : les personnes de l'entreprise **B** qui supervisent la réalisation qu'ils achètent.

Comment: Pour être plussoyée, il faudrait ajouter le point de vue du donneur d'ordre qui fait un appel d'offre, et remonter aux sources du bâtiment pour faire apparaître la notion de chantier (et de sa gestion) identique dans les deux sphères : œuvrer --> action, ouvrage --> réalisation, qu'elle soit matérielle ou immatérielle.

Comment: @cl-r Oui, ma réponse n'est qu'une indication de premier niveau, j'ai trouvé les autres réponses très informatives et n'ai pas voulu les paraphraser, mais tu as raison.

Answer (score 1):

Une petite recherche dans wikipedia donne :

> La maîtrise d'ouvrage (MOA), aussi dénommée maître d'ouvrage est l'entité porteuse du besoin, définissant l'objectif du projet, son calendrier et le budget consacré à ce projet. Le résultat attendu du projet est la réalisation d'un produit, appelé ouvrage.
>
> La maîtrise d'ouvrage maîtrise l'idée de base du projet et représente, à ce titre, les utilisateurs finaux à qui l'ouvrage est destiné.

et

> Le terme maîtrise d'œuvre (souvent abrégé MOE ou MŒ ou Moe ou moe) désigne l'entité retenue par le maître d'ouvrage afin de réaliser le projet dans les conditions de délais, de qualité ainsi que de coûts fixés par ledit projet, le tout conformément à un contrat.

Comment: Si je suis une administration,,donc je suis le Maitre d'ouvrage... et l'entreprise qui execute les travaux pour moi et le MOE ..??

Comment: @OSryx: Oui, c'est bien cela.

Comment: Le maître d’œuvre n’est pas l’entreprise, c’est la personne qui dirige et surveille l’exécution. En matière immobilière, en général les architectes.